# Laravel project: View [welcome] not found. in aws lambda

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda

I clone project from github:

> https://github.com/brefphp/bref

I completed all the steps to initialize the project, namely:

1. install composer
2. cp .env.example .env
3. php artisan key:generate

Then I completed all the steps from the documentation of bref https://bref.sh :

1. Added following in .env:

```
VIEW_COMPILED_PATH=/tmp/storage/framework/views

# We cannot store sessions to disk: if you don't need sessions (e.g. API)
# then use `array`, else store sessions in database or cookies
SESSION_DRIVER=array

# Logging to stderr allows the logs to end up in Cloudwatch
LOG_CHANNEL=stderr
```

2. Clear cache using command:

> php artisan config:clear

After all this step I got exception:

> View [welcome] not found.

But locally in my pc I didn't have an exception.

Also in stacktrace I got:

> at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('/home/pc/code/learning/bref-laravel-demo/resources/views'))
>   in FileViewFinder.php line 79

But welcome.blade.php exist in this directory.

web.php file contain:

```
Route::any('/', function (Request $request) {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Maybe someone had this trouble also?

The structure of project:

[image]

Comment: You checked your routes?

Comment: @Kabelbaan I added route in the post

Comment: Have you also tried: `php artisan cache:clear` and then `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: @Kabelbaan Yes, but still not working:(

Comment: have you checked welcome view file is present in resources/views ?

Comment: @Kabelbaan yes, I wrote this in question

Comment: I don't think it would make any difference but what if you changed `Route::any` to `Route::get` and remove `Request $request` from the function argument

Comment: @Kabelbaan the same

Comment: Could you post the file structure

Comment: what is paths  and compiled set in your config/view.php ?

Comment: @SagarSainkar in view.php:

'compiled' => env(
        'VIEW_COMPILED_PATH',
        realpath(storage_path('framework/views'))
    ),

in .env:

VIEW_COMPILED_PATH=/tmp/storage/framework/views

Comment: @Kabelbaan I added structure

Comment: is  'paths' => [resource_path('views'),] set same in config/view.php

Comment: @SagarSainkar yes

Comment: I look everything fine with your code try php artisan view:clear and check /tmp/storage/framework/views folder have write permissions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206131/discussion-between-sagar-sainkar-and-first).

Comment: try  this  php artisan view:clear

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: @GrigDodon I fixed it, the problem was with my .env configurations. Here you can try working version: https://github.com/OlehKhovanets/aws-lambda-sample if you need

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. Can you tell where exactly is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @EmilEremiev https://github.com/OlehKhovanets/aws-lambda-sample